# Cantor set intersecting a geometric sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was trying to show that the geometric sequence $\{(2/3)^i\}_{i=0}^\infty$ intersects with the Cantor set $C$ at finitely many points, namely, when $i\in\{0,1,3,9\}$, the number $(2/3)^i \in C$. I have verified this for numbers $i \leq 10000$ in Mathematica. I was wondering how the proof of this statement might go. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is tantamount to determining for which $n$ the number $2^n$ has no $1$ in its ternary expansion.  I suspect your conjecture is difficult to prove.  Weisstein has shown it up to $n=10^5$: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ternary.html.

Comment: Posted on [MO here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/172826/cantor-set-intersecting-a-geometric-sequence). Please do not cross-post (nor do so without explicitly saying that you are doing so).